# Clojure - Wait for changes in files

Tags: events, clojure, busy-waiting

I have two files, both 1 byte big (containing nothing more than "1" or "0").

Now inside of the main loop of a program written in Clojure, I would want to wait until either of the files have changed before proceeding. This could be done by busy-waiting, polling the files for changes using slurp. But this is a waste of resources.

How could I do this without busy-waiting?

Answer (score 7):

On the Java VM>7, I would say you could use the Watch Service API. You can use it directly or use of one of the already existing wrapper for Clojure, since there is quite an [abundance](http://www.smashcompany.com/technology/an-abundance-of-file-watchers-in-clojure) of them.

- https://github.com/juxt/dirwatch
- https://github.com/rplevy/ojo
- https://github.com/derekchiang/Clojure-Watch
- etc.

With Clojure-Watch this is how it would look like:

```
(ns clojure-watch.example
 (:require [clojure-watch.core :refer [start-watch]]))

(start-watch [{:path "/home/niko/project/hello"
           :event-types [:create :modify :delete]
           :bootstrap (fn [path] (println "Starting to watch " path))
           :callback (fn [event filename] (println event filename))
           :options {:recursive true}}])
```

```

You can listen to file modifications, deletion and creation. The Watch API uses the native file system support for file change notification when it can.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer of Nicolas, there is also
https://github.com/wkf/hawk which seems to work more efficiently when on MacOS.